Path error occurs after flutter clean. how can fix this?
The path cannot be found when building after ‘flutter clean’
I tryed 'flutter pub get'
The 'com/example/univ_calendar' part of the error message should be 'com.example.univ_calendar'.
I checked the appID in the 'build.gradle' file and upgraded Kotlin.
The error message is as follows
I think this will be solved by changing this part to com/example/u_calendar => com.example.u_calendar
e: file:///C:/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/u_calendar/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/u_calendar/HomeScreenWidgetProvider.kt:10:8 Unresolved reference: es


Hi! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
